# Cisco ASDM on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cisco

How do I tweak [Java on?] Ubuntu 16.04 so that Cisco ASDM (the GUI interface for their ASA firewalls) can run?

Comment: I am running ADSM with Firefox and the icedtea-plugin on Xubuntu 16.04 and OpenJDK8. I haven't been able to launch it with chromium, yet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on Ubuntu 18.04, still works. It may ask you repeatedly if it's ok to accept self-signed certificates, and I had problems with one ASA's .jnlp file not being right, but it's basically worked fine.

From: https://community.cisco.com/t5/firewalls/asdm-on-ubuntu/td-p/3067651
Subject: Installing ASDM on Ubuntu.
Here is what I do.  Install java web start (aka icedtea).
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
Then I have a single line script, which I call asdm.
    javaws https://$1/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
Make it executable:
    chmod +x asdm
Then to run ASDM on say, 1.2.3.4:
    ./asdm 1.2.3.4
This doesn't require any web browser, or web browser support.  It just uses the native installed java directly.

Comment: I'm afraid this would only work on 32-bit systems though.